# Inno Setup Batch compile more than one installer in parallel

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing, inno-setup

I have 13 `.iss` scripts for Inno Setup and I want to compile them in parallel.
At the moment I'm using a `.bat` file for a non-parallel compiling. It takes over two hours, so I want to parallel this.

It's not working with a `start iscc ...`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason, why it should not work with `start`. It actually does work.

Maybe you use a wrong syntax.

The correct syntax is:

```
start "Compiling Setup 1" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe" C:\Setup1\Example.iss
start "Compiling Setup 2" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe" C:\Setup2\Example.iss
```

Note that the first argument to `start` is a window title.

[image]

Comment: Did you really add the title parameter as the first one? Because the wizard starts with **your syntax** (in your question), as the first parameter (`iscc`) is used as a console title, and the second parameter (the `.iss` path) is the "command", what launches the associated application, what is the Inno Setup GUI (`compile32.exe`). See a screenshot added to my answer that shows that **my syntax** works.